# What is the difference between gem list and gem query?

Tags: ruby, rubygems

In `npm` you can list all of installed packages with either `npm list` or `npm list -g` for global package.

In Ruby it seems to me that there is **no local (installed on project folder) gem/package** so we can only install it globally, am I right? and **I want see the list of all installed gems**, some said use `gem list` and others said use `gem query`, so what is the difference between those two?

Answer (score 1):

As per [Rubygems Command reference](http://guides.rubygems.org/command-reference/):

[`gem list`](http://guides.rubygems.org/command-reference/#gem-list):

> Display local gems whose name matches REGEXP
>
> **Usage**: `gem list [REGEXP ...] [options]`

[`gem query`](http://guides.rubygems.org/command-reference/#gem-query):

> Query gem information in local or remote repositories
>
> **Usage**: `gem query [options]`

See links [`gem list`](http://guides.rubygems.org/command-reference/#gem-list) or [`gem query`](http://guides.rubygems.org/command-reference/#gem-query) for relevant options. The guides recommend not using the `gem query` command, but use `gem list` instead.

Comment: It seems that `gem list` and `gem query --local` will display same information, is that right?

Comment: Yes. `gem list` displays all local gems and `gem query --local` displays all gems in the local domain.